# Which of defined in launchSettings.json profiles Visual Studio uses during publication?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core, web-config

I'm trying to configure ASP.NET Core project publication profile for deployment to staging environment. There's preconfigured ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable set on server, but whatever I try Visual Studio keeps adding ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable definition to publishing web.config file. The only way to eliminate it is to delete from launchSettings.json.

This causes several issues:

1. Although learn.microsoft.com says this option should completely
   override the environment variable, in fact the value of
   HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName propery is set to
   "Staging;Environment", concatenated values of environment variable and web.config setting.
2. That in consequesce prevents apropriate
   appsettings.{environment}.json from load and breaks all environment aware logic.
3. I'd prefer to keep ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in launchSettings.json for debugging.

I could not find any setting that controls this behaviour. Is there any?

This is my .pubxml

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release.Main</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>433bb565-5e85-4f1a-9dd4-a7f437fdb534</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>true</_IsPortable>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>http://192.168.0.22</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>auth/main</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>RemoteAgent</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <_SavePWD>False</_SavePWD>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost/DocShellWeb.Sts",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "DocShellWeb.Sts": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Deployed web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="..." arguments="..." stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 706412a5-be0d-452d-a9b0-ce00d799f990-->
```

Comment: You need to add `<EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>` in your `pubxml` file.

Comment: I mean, add this key in your file, but with the appropriate environment. That should add an `environmentVariables` section in your generated `Web.Config`

Comment: @jpgrassi I'd prefer there won't be any ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT at web.config, because even if it set for appropriate environment, the EnvironmentName in runtime is a result of concatenation of the evironment variable and the value in web.config separated by semicolon, e.g. Staging;Staging, Staging;Development etc.

Comment: Well, that is strange then. I just created a sample app, with WebDeploy and it adds the environment correctly for me. Did you try creating a new `profile` and set to FileSystem, just to test things out?

Comment: @jpgrassi well, I mean there is preconfigured ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable set on server, and when it also set at web.config the resulting value isn't overrided (as said in MS docs), but rather concatenated. So, the question is how can I keep it at launchSettings.json for local debugging, but eliminate it in web.config on deployment

Answer (score 5):

The `launchSettings.json` file is only used by Visual Studio during debugging and when running the app via `dotnet run`. It is not used at all or even considered when publishing. If you want to specify a particular environment when you publish, then you need to add add `<EnvironmentName>Staging</EnvironmentName>` to the `pubxml` file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
      ...
      <EnvironmentName>Staging</EnvironmentName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This will have the effect of adding an environment variable declaration for `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` set to `Staging` in your published web.config.

However, that assumes a few things:

1. That you're using IIS to host. Only IIS cares about a web.config file, so if you're hosting with a different web server, you'll obviously need a different strategy.
2. That you want to actually tie the published app to a particular environment in the first place. One of the nice things about ASP.NET Core apps is that they are not built for a particular environment, such as was the case for ASP.NET apps. You can take the same published code and drop it in any environment. The environment then, can be set with an `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMEMT` environment variable on the server (i.e. set it as `Staging` for a staging server, and then any app published there will automatically use the `Staging` environment. Or, it can be set with an app setting if you're using Azure. In either case, you benefit from abstracting the environment from the actual publish code, allowing you to do a CI/CD pipeline, without having to constantly publish.

Comment: `It is not used at all or even considered when publishing`
Unfortunately it DOES (at least in my case). There is ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMEMT variable set on the server, and it's value is 'Staging'. When VS publishes app it generates web.config containing ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMEMT=Development, and I can't get rid of it. When the app runs it gets EnvironmentName: **Staging;Development** (sic!)

Comment: Furthermore, if I set `<EnvironmentName>Staging</EnvironmentName>` at pubxml, the resulting EnvironmentName becomes **Staging;Staging**, what the?..

Comment: @Leff `dotnet publish` sets Development by default in the generated `web.config`, and it seems to ignore both `launchSettings.json` and `*.pubxml`. VS Publish Wizard seems to only perform post processing of web.config, by the `.pubxml` you use. So I believe Chris makes the points clear enough.

Comment: @LexLi Chris is clear enough, but the question is can I eliminate EnvironmentName from publishing web.config somehow?

Comment: @Leff create your own `web.config` as part of your project, and then the commands won't try to generate one.

Comment: @LexLi The same web.config is used for local debugging, it contains **absolute** paths to to executable and assembly, also it should contain EnvironmentName. But it should be totally diffrent for deployment

Comment: @Leff it is too broad to continue discussion on how to set up "local debugging", and the existence of absolute paths and EnvironmentName in `web.config` are red flags (others don't need that for local debugging).

Comment: Ok, let's assume there was no problem at all.
Anyway, thanks for replies. I've solved the issue using web.config transforms.