# VS2017/Angular 7 upgrade deployment error (Development Mode)

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2017, angular7

I did some development in AngularJs a couple years back and really liked it so I  decided to start trying to migrate to a newer version.  It didn't make sense to me to move to Angular 6 given that Angular 7 is out, but the Visual Studio template is still currently using V6.

I have been following this article (https://www.talkingdotnet.com/create-an-angular-7-app-with-visual-studio-2017/) to upgrade the default VS template to V7, but I run into issues when I deploy the application to my web hosting provider.   If I create a new Angular V6 application with the template, it will deploy and run fine.   I can upgrade the V6 template application to V7 using the article I mentioned above and it will run fine in VS locally, but throws the following error when deployed:

**ERROR:**
The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.[image]

**What I have tried:**

**1)**  I tried changing the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable that is on the Debug tab in the project's properties dialog (From 'Development' to 'Production').   I get the same error.[image]

**2)** I tried changing the environment.ts file's production property to true so that both, environment.ts and environment.prod.ts were both true so to rule out it using the wrong version.   This also results in the same error.
[image]

**3)**  I tried using a WinDiff to show all the file differences between the 'ClientApp' folders, comparing V6 and V7.  As this is the only thing I changed from when it works and when it doesn't.  The only differences that look questionable to me are:  main.ts, angular.json, and app.module.ts.   I have included pics of each of those differences (Red is V6, yellow is V7).   I have no idea what else to try at this point, but I did notice that the pathing structure from V6 to V7 isn't the same and is showing in the angular.json image listed.  I'm not sure if this could be the issue or not, but again, the app runs fine on V7 locally in VS so I question that being the cause, but not sure really.

- main.ts

  [image]
- angular.json

  [image][image]
- app.module.ts

  [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55572693/which-of-defined-in-launchsettings-json-profiles-visual-studio-uses-during-publi/55573901?noredirect=1#comment97871789_55573901 Read the discussion to learn more about what happens in `web.config`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Lex...unfortunately, that link doesn't really help my situation as far as I can tell.  The V6 project doesn't have a web.config file either and it runs perfectly fine so I dont expect that to be the issue.  It is only after deleting the ClientApp folder and recreating from angular cli that it stops working.   I went ahead and tried both options that I saw from this article to see if it resolved my issue, but they didn't.  I added a default web.config file to the project, and added the EnvironmentName property as Chris pointed out.  Neither change fixed the issue.

Comment: For testing purposes...I deployed a brand new V6 app with an empty web.config and the EnvironmentName property in the publish xml.  App runs fine.  I deployed a new upgraded V7 app with both changes.  This fails.   I downloaded both web.config files and they are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it working, but I can't completely understand why.

The V7 upgrade (using "ng new ClientApp" command) will create the angular.json file with an outputPath of "dist/ClientApp", where the original V6 template creates this property with only "dist".  If I change the outputPath to "dist" in the V7 application, it will deploy and run as expected.   So, it definitely is related to this setting in angular.json.

There is still one thing that still doesn't make any sense to me.  If I completely remove the entire web directory that is published to the site, change the outputPath back to "dist/ClientApp", and then redeploy, it still works fine.   I did this as a test to verify that this change really did fix the issue I was having before I posted the answer.   I did not expect this to work so it is definitely confusing on why it works.

Comment: Thank you user1011627! You saved me a ton of time!

Comment: Awesome!   Glad it helped!